# New Apple ID not pushed to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

I recently changed my Apple ID from an old email address to my current one. I updated the Apple ID in iTunes and then synced my phone with iTunes. Now, however, when I try to download new apps (or update existing ones), I get the standard notification asking for my Apple ID Password, however the Apple ID that is displays is my old Apple ID. When I enter in my password, it tells me that "Your iTunes Store password was incorrect. Please Try again".

I believe the problem is that for some reason iTunes is not pushing my new Apple ID to the device. Anyone know how to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your iPhone, go into Settings -> Store, sign out of your old Apple ID and sign in with your new one.